# replace urls

Tags: regex, url, text

I have a huge txt file and Editpad Pro list of urls with images on the root folder.

```
http://www.othersite.com/image01.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/image01.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/category/image01.jpg
```

How can I change only that ones that has images on the root using regexp?

```
http://www.othersite.com/image01.jpg
http://www.NEW_WEBSITE.com/image01.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/category/image01.jpg
```

I'm using [the RegExr online app](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Search and replace** (case insensitive, regular expression):

```
http://www\.mysite\.com/([^/]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png))
```

with:

```
http://www\.NEW_WEBSITE\.com/\1
```

---

**EDIT**

And yes, this will also re-base files such as `http://www.mysite.com/.jpg`, if any such files or directories exist.  If anyone doesn't like this then just replace `*` with `+` -- or with `{X,}` if your assumption happens to be that *an image file needs at least a X character name s* etc. etc. -- but **really**, this is probably quite outside the scope of what `lab72` is trying to achieve (i.e. **not** image file name validation.)

Comment: Just a minor problem - an image file needs at least a 1 character name, right? Shouldn't that * be a +? Or do you usually use files like ".jpg"?

Comment: > an image file needs at least a 1 character name, right?
No.

Comment: @phihag - It doesn't need it, but as I said, do you ever have files called ".jpg"?

Comment: @Chris - validating filenames would be a different question.  The assumption is that if the file is in the input list (be it a lonely '.jpg') then it meets the requirements and has to be rebased; I will not make assumptions about what his file names should or should not look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
url1.replace(/((https?:\/\/www.?)(\w*?)(.com\/image\d*?\.(png|gif|jpg))/, 
             "$1newName$3");
```

Something like the above should work. The code is in AS (not compiled though :P) Note that $2 matches the sites name which we are replacing with `yoursite`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
http://www\.mysite\.com/image(.*)
```

with

```
http://www.newsite.com/image$1
```

That being said, you might also be interested in a decent [text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215/what-are-the-best-alternatives-to-notepad). That flash applet is really yucky. You can still use the same regexp, although you'll have to replace the dollar sign `$` with a backslash `\`.

Comment: I guess I should sue the author of that yucky applet for violating my trademark.  Meanwhile, you can find the real EditPad Pro at http://www.editpadpro.com/